# Rsync over custom shell with fifo

Tags: shell, rsync, fifo, rsh

I'm trying to use rsync over a custom shell created with fifo. However I cannot find a way to deal with it :

The script `initsh` to simulate a standard shell by fifo :

```
#!/bin/bash

rm fin
mkfifo fin
rm fout
mkfifo fout
rm ferr
mkfifo ferr
rm farg
mkfifo farg

read arg <farg
cat fin | /bin/bash -i -c "$arg" 1>fout 2>ferr
```

This script works well, you can test it by running `(cat fout &) && echo ls > farg`

The script `rsh` to pass to rsync :

```
#!/bin/bash

shift;
cat fout &
cat ferr 1>&2 &
echo "$@" | tee -a out > farg
cat | tee -a out > fin

sleep 2
kill %%
exit
```

The way to call rsync with :

```
rsync -e './rsh' user@fakehost:/
```

It works well when you run `echo ./rsh`, you got the shell like rsync wait for.
But when rsync runs it, it does not close stdin, and so it waits for the stop (the EOF) of "cat | ...". I also tried with `exec 0<>fin` but it does not work at all.

Is there a trick to close the handle properly ? Or have you any other approach ?

Comment: Does the rsync session actually work, and you're having problems at the end of the session, or does rsync not work at all? And why pipe `cat fin` into bash instead of redirecting fin as standard input to bash? UUOC?

Comment: Yes the rsync session work well and there is only problem at the end. I don't think there is any difference between cat fin | and < fin.

Comment: Well, there's at least the extra overhead of a pipe and an extra process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could wait for the `cat fout` command to end as:

```
#!/bin/bash

shift;
cat fout &
foutid=$!
cat ferr 1>&2 &
echo "$@" | tee -a out > farg
cat | tee -a out > fin <&0 &

wait $foutid

sleep 2
kill %%
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works ! However I don't understand why we need `cat | ` and `<&0` ?

Comment: you don't need `cat |` it should work without it. `<&0` prevents tee from blocking when sent to bg - I'm not sure why it block in the first place.